# What is a good language used in linux that I should pursue?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu

Hey, new to Linux here, I just installed Ubuntu on my system the other night; so now I'm dual booting with Ubuntu and Windows 7.
I'm fairly new to programming, I've only been at it for about 6-8 months. I would say the last two months I've  gotten a bit more serious about it. But I guess you could say I'm still only checking things out.

So, for the most part I've been programming in C#, I most do CL but I sometimes try some GUI's.
Now that I'm trying Ubuntu Linux, I'm looking to find a (I guess) native language to Linux, that will work for me.

So, if there is something close to C#, or something that won't be to hard of a shift, please do inform me; like I said above I'm mostly into CLs, but I like to make GUIs now and then. So anything that will allow me to do that.

Also, if you could recommend good software that would go along with that language, it would be very helpful. Unless I could somehow write it in a word-processor and then build it myself.. Again, not to sure how Linux works yet..

Yet, I'm hoping that along with this communities help, I might learn even a little bit more; thank you, and I hope you have a great day.

[Edit] Sorry, forgot to mention, I have been using Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Java is probably the closest language to C#, but you can still use C# on Linux, via [Mono](http://mono-project.com). That includes writing UIs, with any of Silverlight/Moonlight, GTK# or Windows Forms (with some restrictions). You can use the [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) IDE, too.

Comment: Would java be more native to Linux than C#? I'm guessing yes since C# is from Windows os, right?

Comment: @James: Java is a lot more widely used in Linux than C# has, certainly. The virtual machine abstractions are reasonably similar though, in that neither is really native but both typically involve JIT-compilers to generate native code on the fly.

Comment: Okay, just a few questions then.. Can I develop CLs with Java? And, what is a JIT-Compiler?  Sorry, I know these must seem like very simple questions, I'm just very new to all of this..

Comment: I don't know what CLs are. A just in time (JIT) compiler is a compiler that compiles your code into native instructions on the fly while it's running on a virtual machine rather than upfront (as is the case with C etc.).

Comment: @James: Yes, you can develop command-line applications in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really focus on "language". Here are some general guidelines.

1. Pick a language different from the one(s) you already know so that you learn something new. This is purely educational.
2. Pick a language depending on the problem you're trying to solve. No one uses python for systems programming and (almost) no one uses C for writing system administration "glue" scripts.
3. Contribute to a project that you find interesting in small ways. That way, you'll get first hand experience with "real" code.

That being said, here are some language recommendations. These are biassed by my own background so don't take it *too* seriously.

1. C is sort of the latin of programming languages (to quote Zed Shaw). It's something that's very close to the metal and worth learning.
2. Python is increasing in popularity especially on Ubuntu. It's probably worth learning.
3. Java, C# and C++ have a lot of industry acceptance so it's probably worth knowing them.
4. Javascript is gaining a lot of ground with the increasing number of web apps out there.
5. Perl is nice for sysad work and text munging if you're into that kind of thing.
6. Ruby is quite popular for DSLs, tools and web apps.
7. Shell is useful for quick and dirty scripts. Also, you'll find a lot of scaffolding written using it.
8. Learn a few markups like HTML, LaTeX and the modern ones like markdown etc.

Comment: Right now I'm not sure that I have a problem that needs solving; I've just been messing around with C#.
Also, how can I contribute to a project?

I like your answer, although it just seems a little vague for me at this point..

Comment: The problem is that there's no real single language that you should learn. I was just trying to state some general ideas that might offer guidance.

Comment: Yeah I know, but right now I feel I need one that would make a good migrating entry point into the Linux world. I'm so used to Windows os..

Comment: I'd recommend one of the "Scripting" languages then. Python or Ruby. Take your pick. They have relatively smooth learning curves and you can get quick results to give you the boost that you need to keep going.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way you would recommend to start using one of these? I think I may try python, I've heard it's name more than ruby lol.

Comment: Well, the first step after getting python is to go through the tutorial at docs.python.org. Once you're somewhat comfortable, start a small project (perhaps a clone of your favourite C# project). When you get more comfortable, you might be able to find a Python package out there which you can contribute fixes to.

Answer (score 0):

[Mono](http://mono-project.com/) is an open-source implementation of the .Net CLR.  You can install that and keep on writing your C#.  Yay!

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention, I have been trying mono.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page). It's an open source version of Microsoft .NET and C# is one of the supported languages. This way the skills you acquire in Linux/C# will be easily transferable to Windows/C#

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying that so far, just looking for something different sorta.

Answer (score 0):

You could try GO from Google.
It seems to have both Linux and Windows support.

http://code.google.com/p/go/

Comment: Weird, never knew google had their own language.. They have everything lol! Have you personally tried it? If so, what are your views on it?

Comment: I have so many things on right now I can't say I've tried it but it look very good and may be the next big thing. 

Actionscript 3, flex from Adobe looks good too, but they seem to have dropped support for linux :(